# Determining make model and year of bmx frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I'm restoring a 20" bmx frame and would like to know maker, model and year so I can restore to original as possible. There are two numbers on the bottom of crank housing.

```
                     MBI-2325 
                     294558
```

is on top and

```
                     WIU253
                     P0153D
```

is on bottom.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you include images of the frame and anything that may stand out such as logos, decals, interesting lugs etc it will help greatly in identifying it if possible. Welcome to SE Bicycles!

Answer (score 7):

Google is your friend.  Based on [a report from the South Yorkshire Police](http://www.southyorks.police.uk/sites/default/files/20140934%20-%20Bike%20Data%20-%20publish.xls) , they received a report of a stolen BMX with "mbi-2325" as the "serial number" in 2010.
Seems to be a mistake in that was a frame model and the serial number is one of the other values.

However this same police report lists it as

> MIRRACO   BLEND 2 BMX BIKE BROWN 09

which means little to me.  More Google returns http://www.vitalbmx.com/product/feature/Mirraco-Blend-Two-Complete-Bike,2275

[image]

> Another dope complete bike from Mirraco. Here are the specs:

- Frame: 20.5” T/T full chromoly with D.B. down-tube, with integrated head tube, MID bottom bracket and 5mm thick dropouts
- Fork: full chromoly with 3/8” dropouts
- Headset: FPD 1-1/8” integrated sealed
- Crankset: M3 3-piece chromoly 170mm, 19mm x 8-spline chromoly axle
- BB Set: MID BB with R12 sealed bearings
- Sprocket: M3 alloy 28t
- Freewheel: 10t 1-piece driver RHD cassette
- Chain: KMC Z410 nickel plated
- Pedals: Wellgo Lite alloy 9/16” chromoly axles
- Handlebar: M3 2-piece 7.5” chromoly 2.0T
- Stem: M3 Downside alloy Aheadset 1-1/8”
- Grips: Duo Scotty Cranmer
- Saddle: M3 Blend Pivotal
- Seat Post: Pivotal alloy 25.4mm x 200mm single bolt
- Seat Clamp: M3 alloy 28.6mm
- Front Hub: M3 alloy 36-hole 3/8” chromoly axle, 2 sealed bearings
- Rear Hub: M3 alloy cassette 36-hole with 14mm chromoly hollow axle, RHD, 4 sealed bearing, 10t 1-piece driver
- Rims: Ale x double wall DM-22 black anodized front, DM-24 chromed  rear, 36-hole with eyelets
- Spokes: 14g stainless
- Tires: Maxxis Grifter 20 x 2.1” front, 1.85” rear, 110/100 PSI
- Pegs: steel pegs (1 pair)
- Rotor: SST Oryg with SST top and lower cables
- Brakes: Tektro FX-570 alloy rear U-brake with soft grey pads
- Brake Lever: Snafu C-Lever, alloy with hinge

> Weight: 26.1 lb./11.8 kg
>   Colours: Flat Brown, Mica Blue

Comment: A sale link http://www.pinkbike.com/buysell/625695/   but this may not be "original spec"